# И снова API для аниме

Tags: python, json, requests

Я НАДЕЮСЬ, что нашёл идеальный апи, но не могу получить данные из json! Код приложен ниже.

```py
import requests
import json
from pprint import pprint
url="https://api.anilibria.tv/v2/getTitle?code=yasuke"
r = requests.get(url=url)
text = json.loads(r.text)
txt = json.dumps(text)
#pprint(txt)
for data in txt:
    id = data["id"]
    print(id)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 3):

У вас переменная `text` уже содержит словарь, так что вот это

```py
txt = json.dumps(text)
```

уже лишнее

чтобы распечатать `id` вам просто надо сделать так

```py
print(text["id"])
```

вывод

```
9004
```

Плюс у ответа есть метод `json`, который сразу ответ преобразует в словарь.
И код сократится до

```py
import requests
import json

from pprint import pprint
url="https://api.anilibria.tv/v2/getTitle?code=yasuke"
r = requests.get(url=url)
text = r.json()
print(text["id"])
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо, но я уже догодался, НО ВСЕ РАВНО ОГРОМНОЕ СПАСИБО!

Comment: @RedFox на здоровье! Можете отметить ответ ка полезный и принятый

Comment: @Dmitry - спасибо, крутой ответ! Я вопрос не задавал, просто тоже люблю аниме!